# How do I make a thumbnail enlarge transitively?

Tags: javascript

How do I make a thumbnail enlarge transitively during for instance 3 sec when you hover over it? (as it is in ppt slideshow) my code worked in ie 5.5 but doesn't work in chrome

my code worked in ie 5.5 but doesn't work in chrome

Comment: please attach the code

Comment: You can use CSS `transition` and swap the class.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: IE 5 uses JScript. That's not even JavaScript. Also, IE is dead.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl In the corporate environment too?

Comment: @deEr. I would hope so.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Do you find any statistics, for China too, at the web?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [How To Zoom on Hover](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp)

There is no need to use JavaScript. You can stick with CSS transisitons.

Here is a modified example of the code linked above:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.zoom {
  transition: transform 3s;
  border: thin solid #000;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img class="zoom" src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100" />
```

Comment: i want to enlarge thumbnail gradient transitively

Comment: when i mouse over the thumbnail large picture opens gradient transitively below the thumbnail

Comment: @anomondi that does not make any sense. You would have to provide code to back up what you are saying.

Comment: i can't write whole code here-it"s too long

Comment: @anomondi then add it to your question above. You can edit your post.